# Changing column in set update

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I use a case statement in Set Column? I have multiple columns that need to be updated but the statement is quite similar. The only difference is what I'm selecting.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET  A.COLUMN2 = (SELECT....
```

I want to update column2 to Column1 without repeating the same block of code.

Note: I'm using LISTAGG

---

Is there any way I could distinct both of the columns without trying to separate it in one query the make a subquery

I'm using this query and I know that listagg don't have the capabilities to distinct unless you distinct it first before using listagg

```
  SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN1 , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN1) AS COLUMN1 , 
     LISTAGG(COLUMN2 , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN2) AS COLUMN1
    FROM (SELECT COLUMN1 , COLUMN2  FROM TABLE2 B
    WHERE A.COLUMN3 =  B.COLUMN3
    GROUP BY COLUMN1 , COLUMN2);


COLUMN1    COLUMN2 
EGG        PIE
EGG        BREAD
```

Expected output

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2
EGG         PIE; BREAD
```

Comment: put full query of what you want please

Comment: Yes, you can use case _expressions_, but also take a look at  @ishando's answer

Comment: You can do something like `SET column1 = CASE WHEN variable_1 = 'Yes' then (select ...) else column1 end,
    column2 = CASE WHEN variable_2 = 'Yes' then (select ...) else column2 end ...`, but it's perhaps not the best way. (All columns updated "transaction wise", consider triggers etc.)

Comment: I can't really understand the question. Do you need an update or a select query? If you need an update, please post some sample data before and after the update.

Comment: A [mcve] would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
UPDATE table1
SET (column1, column2 ...) = (SELECT col1, col2 ...)
```

Comment: Similar to this but I have a loop, so I'm expecting like SET(CASE WHEN variable_1 = 'Yes' then column1 else column2) = (Select .....

Comment: Nope, you can't do it that way.